# Text in a PDFLaTeX file is not completely visible in the PDF viewer , but in the thumbnails are complete

Tags: pdftex

This is not really a question TeX, but I think we could find an answer here.

I downloaded an old PDF file generated with pdfTeX. The problem is that when I open the PDF, some text lines in the right margin are not visible:
[image]
Apparently it's a problem about output page size v/s page size declarated in .tex file (probably lettersize or A4), because viewing the file properties in the PDF viewer (Foxit), the size of the "visible" page is 16 x 23 cm; however, text lines not visibles in the PDF, are visibles in the file's thumbnails:
[image]

I think the text is not visible in the file is hidden in some way; otherwise, it could not be completely in the thumbnails. **Unfortunately, I haven't the document tex file**. My question is: Is there any way to make the document appear properly, making visible the text is lost along the right margin? I've tried opening the file with Inkscape, but Inkscape don't recognize the Computer Modern fonts

The document is disponible [in this link](ftp://ftp.ing-mat.udec.cl/pub/ing-mat/asignaturas/521234/evaluaciones/EX2-98.pdf).

Comment: The Gimp, Imagemagik, Adobe Reader and Okular fails as well on my Debian. What produces the thumbnails, windows? [Graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) could be a more suitable place to ask this question.

Comment: on line 24 of the file you see `/MediaBox [0 0 453.543 651.968]`  changing that to `/MediaBox [0 0 553.543 651.968]` makes the full page visible

Comment: @Clément you should have used emacs:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I should definitely use emacs ;-) Did you solved the exam at the same time ?

Comment: actually the above still clips the bottom: better is `/MediaBox [0 -140 553.5430 580]` The important thing is **do not change the total character length** when editing pdfs in this way. [resulting pdf](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BPZQ6.png)

Comment: What program should I use to change the /Mediabox value?

Comment: Any text editor. As @DavidCarlisle points out, emacs reigns supreme among these :)

Comment: note I answered so I could format the command line and as it's marginally close to the topic as it's a tex generated file, but the question is off topic really; so I voted to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the MediaBox in the file, with a text editor such as emacs or on the commandline with for example this sed command

```
sed -b -e 's/MediaBox \[...................\]/MediaBox [0 -140 553.5430 580]/' EX2-98.pdf > EX2-98-new.pdf
```

where `-b` means binary mode and don't mess with line endings, an you need exactly that many `.` this will leave the corrected file in `EX2-98-new.pdf`

You can do the other pdf in the collection in a similar way, if they have media boxes with different number of characters then adjust the `.` accordingly and add or remove (any) decimal places in the new media box to keep the character length the same.